# DataGrid is not showing values WPF

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` which is showing values only in the first column even though there are  values in the other cells. Here is my code:

**XAML:**

```
<Grid ShowGridLines="False">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"
              GridLinesVisibility="None" IsReadOnly="True"
              Name="AvdrEventsDataGrid" VerticalAlignment="Top"
              Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
              Loaded="AvdrEventsDataGrid_Loaded" CanUserSortColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <!--<Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />-->
                <!--<Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Wingdings"/>-->
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
    </DataGrid>
    <Button Content="Run!" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Name="btnRun" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="20,0,0,0"
            Width="75" Grid.Row="1" Click="btnRun_Click"/> 
</Grid>
```

**C#:**

```
DataTable _resulTable=new DataTable();
AvdrEventBuilder avdrEventBuilder=new AvdrEventBuilder();
_resulTable = avdrEventBuilder.GetEventData();
AvdrEventsDataGrid.DataContext = _resulTable;
```

Also I am changing the color of the first column like this

```
int i = 0;
foreach (var row in _resulTable.Rows)
{
    var cell = AvdrEventsDataGrid.GetCell(i, 0);
    cell.Background = Brushes.Gray;
    cell.Foreground = Brushes.White;
    i++;
    cell.Width = 100;
}
```

The issue is I can see values only in the first column even though there are values in other dataset columns. I also tried    `AvdrEventsDataGrid.ItemsSource = @object;` this using a collection of class objects. It showing the same blank values. Please help.

Comment: Just an idea: try to set the foreground of the other cells too. I might be wrong, but my hunch is that the foreground of your cells inherits the white foreground from the header style and thus you are not seeing them even though they are there.

Comment: What is your `_resulTable`? Can you show it

Comment: _resulTable is just a dataset.

Comment: Please just follow the example from the [DataGrid Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN to see how it works. When you have all of your data visible, *then* start adding your styling.